# todolist double click to add class?

Tags: javascript

I am making a todo list... When the task is finished i need to be able to click it and then add a class to that item... It works but I have to double click.. Any suggestions?

```
 list.onclick = function() {
        var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            list[i].onclick = function() {
                if (!this.classList.contains("checked") || this.classList.contains("checked")) {
                    this.classList.add("checked");
                } else {
                    this.classList.remove("checked");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove this part of your code? `|| this.classList.contains("checked")`

Comment: `!this.classList.contains("checked") || this.classList.contains("checked"))` isnt that  always true?

Comment: Just use `this.classList.toggle("checked");`. and Recheck the condition

Comment: Thanks for the response I have tried the suggestions but still need to double click...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand purpose of this function is to check or uncheck list element each time user clicks on it. For this purpose, first of all we need to identify if 'class' exists or not and remove it. In other cases just add that 'class' to classList attribute.

```
list.onclick = function() 
{
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        list[i].onclick = function() 
        {
            if (this.classList.contains("checked") 
            {
                this.classList.remove("checked");
            } 
            else 
            {
                this.classList.add("checked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```